# Integer Factorization problem - New Idea

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algorithms, factoring

I been thinking about slightly different approach of solving the problem, and I want you to tell me **if** my idea is **reasonable** and if it's **original**(If someone already thought about this, I would be interested to know).

I want to factor some integer $N$. So I represent it as fallow, where $x,k,a$ are integers.

$$x^2 - N = ka$$

Next I constract a function

$$f(i) = (x + ik)^2 - N$$

And I want to find when $f(i)$ is a square so I can use [Fermat factoring method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_factorization_method).

So first lets simplify it.

$f(i) = (x + ik)^2 - N= x^2 + 2ik + (ik)^2 - N = 2ixk + (ik)^2 + ka=$
$$k(2ix + ki^2 + a)$$

Next I want to use similar ideas as used in [quadratic sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_sieve) to find some vector representation of $2ix + ki^2 + a$ in the bounds of $B$ aka B-Smooth numbers. $k$ will always be part of the vector as it divides all the values in $f(i)$.

The benefit of this method is that the growth of  $2ix + ki^2 + a$ will be slower than $h(i) = (x+i)^2 - N$ and there for it will be easier to look for B-Smooth numbers.

After finding enough B-Smooth numbers I can find a square.

Is it reasonable? Is it original? What do you think?

Comment: Knuth (*The Art of Computer Programming*, 4.5.4) discusses a few simple linear speed-ups (by factors $\stackrel<\approx 10$) depending on residues of $N$ modulo some small moduli, but these seem unrelated to your suggestions. However, I suspect that either one will not easily find a large factor $k$ of $x^2-N$, or the need to cancel it in the linear algebra part of the sieve may make the search slightly less efficient (as if $B$ was one prime smaller). Finally, $2ix+ki^2+a$ grows by $\approx 2x$ in each step - as does $h(i)$ ...